# Python: problem of using categorical crosses trophy in CNN to classify multiple object

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using A.I. algorithm sample from github to study image recognition and processing. 600 jpeg images for 4 dota hero classes are imported and resize to 64*64 pixels. 400 images are training set, and 200 images are testing set for this code. The problem is the python program output give me: this dota II hero is sven and also give me the option five: this is a non dota hero,  where the image that putting in to test is the image of mirana. Here is part of my code:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN
 classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss =                         
'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/dota_training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/dota_test_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'categorical')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 1000,
epochs = 3,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 500)

# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/test_2.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'sven'
    print("This is a Sven.")
if result[0][0] == 2.0:
    prediction = 'mirana'
    print("This is a mirana.")
if result[0][0] == 3.0:
    prediction = 'Wraith_King'
    print("This is a Wraith King.")
if result[0][0] == 4.0:
    prediction = 'Phantom_Lancer'
    print("This is a Phantom Lancer.")
else:
    prediction = 'non_dota hero'
    print("This is a non dota hero.")
```

I suspect is it the last part if and else problem. How I able to correct my problem, so the program can provide the correct answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your else block is only an `else` for the last `if`.

```
if result[0][0] == 4.0:
    prediction = 'Phantom_Lancer'
    print("This is a Phantom Lancer.")
else:
    prediction = 'non_dota hero'
    print("This is a non dota hero.")
```

Change the other `ifs` to `elifs`:

```
if result[0][0] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'sven'
    print("This is a Sven.")
elif result[0][0] == 2.0:
    prediction = 'mirana'
    print("This is a mirana.")
elif result[0][0] == 3.0:
    prediction = 'Wraith_King'
    print("This is a Wraith King.")
elif result[0][0] == 4.0:
    prediction = 'Phantom_Lancer'
    print("This is a Phantom Lancer.")
else:
    prediction = 'non_dota hero'
    print("This is a non dota hero.")
```

Comment: Thank you CJ59, its improve, but it still give me the answer sven even i put in mirana pic to test. I change the IF become ELIF according to your advice.

Comment: If it's not producing correct predictions, then you should look at how well your model predicted your test data. There are a lot of things you can do to change how your model is trained. I couldn't speculate without seeing the actual data and modeling metrics (I would choose not to speculate if you provided those things).

Comment: Thank C59J for your useful advice, my another question is will the pixels, size and number of the images affect the training data results? Should i put more image and increase the resolution of the image in order to improve the model.

Comment: Both of those things will probably improve the model if it's performing poorly on your test data. If it's performing well on your test data but then poorly when you challenge it with new images, you have a different problem.

Comment: Hi, C59J i know what my mistakes, it should be
if result[0][0] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'sven'
    print("This is a Sven.")
elif result[0][1] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'mirana'
    print("This is a mirana.")
instaed of 
if result[0][0] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'sven'
    print("This is a Sven.")
elif result[0][0] == 2.0:
    prediction = 'mirana'
    print("This is a mirana.")